# HEIC,HEIF,HEVC,TIF image converter into jpg react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs

I have an application where user can upload multiple images and will be displayed on a web chat. But I'm not able to upload the tif/tiff/heic/heif/hevc images , since it has been not rendered by the browser. How do I upload it in react
thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have not started implementing yet. Need some guidence